# Checking a checkbox with dalekjs

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, dalekjs

This feels like the stupidest question ever asked on SO, but I'm having no luck with things I've tried to check a simple checkbox within a DalekJS test.

So far I have tried clicking it:-

```
.click('#checky')
```

I've tried checking it:-

```
.execute(function() {
    document.getElementById('checky').checked = true;
}
```

I've tried setting it:-

```
.setValue('#checky', true)
```

Which got dalek very upset...

I've tried shouting at it and swearing at it.  But no dice.  I've looked through the dalek library and there doesn't seem to be an [action](http://dalekjs.com/docs/actions.html) to suit.  So I'm hoping someone will have any suggestions or help...

Please accept my apologies for the lameness of this question...

Comment: Clicking the input element seems to work in my tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('#checky').prop('checked',true)
```

or

```
document.createElement("checky").setAttribute('checked',true)
```

tell me what you find out

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No luck I'm afraid.

Comment: this solved the problem ```$('#checky').prop('checked',true)```.  Thank you very much.  Seems that your code was working and the CSS was covering the results. +1 and many thanks.